# Why is this subtraction failing?

Tags: javascript

```
> 76.74 -20;
56.739999999999995
> 96.74 -20;
76.74
> 66.74 -20;
46.739999999999995
> 76.74 -20;
56.739999999999995
> 46.74 - 20;
26.740000000000002
> 86.74 - 20;
66.74
```

I am on Ubuntu 64 bits, and I am trying this on iojs. Also fails on Terminal:

```
echo $((76.74-40))
36.739999999999995
```

Comment: Due to floating point errors...? This is very common, try something like BC which has higher accuracy

Comment: I tried parseFloat, what should I try?

Comment: `bc <<< "76.74 - 40"`

Comment: I mean on JavaScript

Comment: `(76.74*1000-40*1000)/1000)`

Comment: It's not a bad question just because everyone who knows anything about floating point knows the answer.  I think the question is fairly clear, even if the answer is trivial.  Upvoted only because it was at negative score.

Comment: @PeterCordes You should never upvote just to cancel out downvotes. Only if you think it's an honestly good question. Don't take away somebody else's right to vote

Comment: @vihan you are taking away peter right to vote. At least trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Because [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) math has limited precision, and not every real number is representable, even in the range from min to max representable value.

Unlike integers, the set of real numbers is an uncountable infinity, so this isn't a fixable problem.  (well, other than using something else.  e.g. fixed-point, arbitrary-precision, or simply rounding before printing.  (e.g. print to only 2 places after the decimal.))